# How to take a screenshot in Dragon Age: Inquisition?

Tags: technical-issues, dragon-age-inquisition

Origin doesn't have built in screenshot support. DA:I doesn't seem to have a screenshot option. I try launching from Steam but I'm not getting the Steam overlay. How best to take screenshots of Dragon Age: Inquisition?

Answer (score 8):

In the PC version pressing the [print screen] key on your keyboard will screen cap to My Documents\Bioware\Dragon Age Inquisition\Screen Shots

I've tried this and it works, your screen will probably freeze momentarily as the screen cap is saved.

Comment: I'm trying to get away from FRAPS as it doesn't play nicely with Origin's overlay system. I found that you can do "PerfOverlay.DrawFPS 1" at the console to display an FPS counter, which is nice. My main concern is that the print screen button might not work in controller mode, which is what I tend to use.

Comment: Just tested this and the printscreen key still works even in controller mode. I did have to disable the Dropbox screenshot sharing setup, however.